# Jacobian of a trajectory given by a matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, jacobian, kronecker-product

I need to get the jacobian of the function $x(t) = e^{At} x_0 $.
so,
I was thought about applying the vectorization and Kronecker product:

$ d \, vec \, x  = (x_0^T \otimes I) \, d \, vec (e^At)$.

But how should I continue?... I don't know how to write $(e^At)$ in terms of A

A is diagonalizable, and T is an orthonormal set of eigenvectors.

$A = T diag [\lambda_1,..., \lambda_n ] T^{-1}$, so

$e^{At} = T diag [e^\lambda_1,..., e^\lambda_n  ] T^{-1}$